# Horizontal Scaling of RDBMS database in JAVA ORM application

Tags: java, orm, scalability, rdbms, horizontal-scaling

What is the latest and most optimised approach of horizontal scaling the RDBMS using Java application? I know sharding as one option but that comes with its own set of complexity and even more complex is the failover servers.

Thanks,

Comment: read, write, or both?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 possible options for horizontal scaling of database: replication, sharding and clustering. If you need to scale writes also than you may choose between sharding and clustering. For clustering the solution depends on your database vendor.